# How to return all rows if using if (empty($variable))?

Tags: php

I am using this query below and it only returns the first query in the entry if i use only the if (empty($field1)) to display.  If i fill in the print(""); it works but i want to use the if (empty($field1)) snippet to display.  How can i do it?

```
$sql="SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE p_id='$pid'
      and k_id='$kid' ORDER BY id DESC";  
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

if ($result == "")
{
    echo "";
}

echo "";

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows == 0)
{
    print("");
}
elseif($rows > 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $field1 = $row['field1'];
        $field2 = $row['field2'];
        print("");
    }
}

if (empty($field1)) {
    echo ""; //Thats right, i don't want anything to show for this portion
} else {
   echo "<div id=comments>Comments</div><br>
   <div id=entries>$field1 and $field2</div>";
}
```

Comment: are you executing your query twice or is it just because of an inconsistancy in the example?

Comment: How many rows do you expect it to return? What are `p_id` and `k_id`?

Comment: didnt' realize i was will fix that.

Comment: p_id is the post id and k_id is another variable

Comment: Check the values of $pid and $kid - possibly they aren't what you expect?

Comment: You are selecting `field1` and `field2`, but later you are using `$row['field1_name']` and `$row['field2_id']`.

Comment: the valeus are corect not sure why only 1 entry would show.  the db has more than 10 for this id

Comment: @karolis that is inconsistency.  my fault let me fix that in the question.

Comment: Please consider reposting your actual code. The code provided doesn't show where you use `$field1` and `$field2`

Comment: Anybody? I updated the question after feedback and as said before, the entries are returning properly as long as i use the print("$field1 and $field2"); but as i am using the if(empty) its only returning one row.  What i can do to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do? somthing like this:

```
$sql="SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE p_id='$pid' and k_id='$kid' ORDER BY id DESC";  
$result=mysql_query($sql)  or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($rows > 0)
  echo "here are your entries\n";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['field1']." ";
    echo $row['field2']."\n";
}
```

another way

```
$sql="SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE p_id='$pid' and k_id='$kid' ORDER BY id DESC";  
$result=mysql_query($sql)  or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($rows > 0)
  echo "here are your entries\n";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if (empty($row['field1'])) {
        echo " ";
    } else {
    echo $row['field1']." ";
    echo $row['field2']."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: that would work but i need to have to dislay using f (empty($field1)) {
echo "";
} else {

   echo "here are your entries";

}

Answer (score 1):

i believe mysql_fetch_array only returns one row
http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_mysql_fetch_array.asp

also ur sure that neither p_id and k_id are not unique?

i would also try      $sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE p_id='$pid'
      and k_id='$kid' ORDER BY id DESC";

just to see if that yields any different results, you can always parse out just the two fields from the return data

TRY THIS TO START WITH (the $results variable is just confusing things):

```
  $sql="SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE p_id='$pid'
      and k_id='$kid' ORDER BY id DESC";  

      $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

   $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

  if($rows == 0)
  {
  print("");

  }else{

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
          if ($row['field1'] == "")
            {
               print("");
            }else{
           $field1 = $row['field1'];
           print($field1)
            }

if ($row['field2'] == "")
            {
               print("");
            }else{
           $field1 = $row['field2'];
           print($field2)
            }
  }

}
```

Comment: i have checked that works.  the query works i use the print("") to display but if you notice i am using the if empty snipet so maybe thats why?

Comment: well per the other post about running your query twice and not really using the results in $results i would say clean up the code, run it, see what happens, then update us here.  maybe update the code block in your post too since it looks a little messy

Comment: i would also say to maybe run your query in a sql window (as opposed to just within your code).  this will give u a real understanding of what data is in there and what your query actually returns

Comment: ok if i use print("$field1 and $field2"); then all etnires show up, but as you can see i am not doing that, i want to use the  if (empty($field1)) {
echo "";
} else {

   echo "$field1 and $field2";

}
instead of print("");

Comment: see my edits and if that fits your needs.  what i dont get is a null field is a null field.  meaning printing "" is the equivalent to printing a values thats set to null.

Comment: What i have are options like comments so i don't want the heading "comments" and then the comments under it to show if no comments are there.  So only if comments are there the heading "comments" and the comments should come up.

Comment: well then your not showing all the code.  because where ever your printing your heading "comments" should check $row['fieldX'] == "" prior to it being written to the screen.  if the comments field is blank then dont put the heading comments.

Comment: i believe $field1 is out of scope at that point and is actually a newly created variable (kinda new to php so i could be wrong).  if im right and that is the problem then declare $field1 outside of the while loop or any other if statements.  than the last if will be referencing the right value